# How to use FacebookSDK 3.1 for iOS5

Tags: facebook, ios5, ios6

I'm having an issue with using facebookSDK 3.1 on both iOS6 and iOS5. 
I got everything running correctly on iOS6 using the tutorials and resources from developers.facebook.com.

Now for iOS5 I'm using the [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:] and I see a web authentication pop up in iOS simulator.

However on the callback, I always get back FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed. 
not sure what I need to do to get this working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I failed to include this method in the app delegate. Adding this fixed the issue

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // We need to properly handle activation of the application with regards to SSO
    // (e.g., returning from iOS 6.0 authorization dialog or from fast app switching).
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}